# R: install packages languageserver had non-zero exit status

Tags: r, vscode-extensions

### Introduction

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

I am currently install the *languageserver* packages on R, to use the R VS Code extension.

### Problematic

But when I execute the `install.packages("languageserver")` in R with the Ubuntu's terminal, I have this error:

```
> install.packages("languageserver")
Installing package into ‘/home/mathieu-s/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘curl’, ‘httr’, ‘lintr’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/curl_4.3.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 793345 bytes (774 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 774 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/httr_1.4.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 159950 bytes (156 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 156 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/lintr_2.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 219142 bytes (214 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 214 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/languageserver_0.3.12.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 78124 bytes (76 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 76 KB

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/mathieu-s/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/curl’
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/mathieu-s/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/httr’
ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘lintr’
* removing ‘/home/mathieu-s/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/lintr’
ERROR: dependency ‘lintr’ is not available for package ‘languageserver’
* removing ‘/home/mathieu-s/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/languageserver’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpVaqLTX/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("languageserver") :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("languageserver") :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("languageserver") :
  installation of package ‘lintr’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages("languageserver") :
  installation of package ‘languageserver’ had non-zero exit status
```

But I don't know how to solve this error, can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should install `libcurl4-openssl-dev` in Ubuntu, try the following codes in Ubuntu `terminal`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

then try again to install `languageserver` package in `R`